# How to properly do wedges

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra

> Does $A\wedge B=A\wedge C$ imply that $B=C$?

I need help figuring this out because I am lost on this

Comment: What do you mean by "wedges"? I've only seen wedge used as an operator (specifically the exterior product), not a relation.

Comment: wedges are 2 vectors. for example ab can be written as A wedges B. You see them in parellograms

Comment: This does not make any sense. There is no equality or relation being expressed.

Comment: So it's a pair of vectors? Are you asking whether if $A \wedge B = A \wedge C$ that $B = C$?

Comment: My professor said it was a wedge. it looks like a upside down V. If there is a way I can show you all then I will.

Comment: ConMan yes. Exactly. can you help me?

Comment: Im sorry I did not put the math symbols on my post. I am new to here so I am trying to see how to properly do it

Comment: @Zman [This tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) should help you with that.

Comment: @Bye_World thanks

Comment: Im still have trouble trying to put my wedge symbol on here. It says I need to do coding but where?

Comment: @Zman To get $A \wedge B$, you type `$A \wedge B$`.

Answer (score 3):

You asked "If A wedges B and A wedges C ...". Usually, a statement of the form "If X and Y" only makes sense if X and Y are things that can be true or false, hence our confusion. However, if we interpret it as "If $A \wedge B = A \wedge C$, does $B = C$?" - in other words, if the exterior vector products are equal are the vectors themselves equal?

The answer is no. If $A \wedge B = A \wedge C$, then it is satisfied in general if the vectors $A$ and $B - C$ are parallel, or the vector $A = 0$.

Comment: Are you saying towards the end of your statement that if vectors A and B minus C are parallel? I was following your statement up to that point

Comment: @Zman Yes, because $A\wedge (B-C)=0$ hence $A$ and $B-C$ are parallel (with the hands: the area of the parallelogram defined by $A$ and $B-C$ is $0$).